# How to use Selenium for 24x7 until any error comes

Tags: python, selenium

Now, I am using selenium to execute script "window.performance.timing" to get the full load time of a page. It can run without opening a browser. I want this keep running 24x7 and return the loading time.

Here is my code:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
import getpass

u=getpass.getuser()
print(u)

# # initialize Chrome options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\%s\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data'%(u))

source = "https://na66.salesforce.com/5000y00001SgXm0?srPos=0&srKp=500"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)

driver.get(source)
driver.find_element_by_id("Login").click()
while True:
    try:
        navigationStart = driver.execute_script("return window.performance.timing.navigationStart")
        domComplete = driver.execute_script("return window.performance.timing.domComplete")
        loadEvent = driver.execute_script("return window.performance.timing. loadEventEnd")

        onloadPerformance = loadEvent - navigationStart

        print("%s--It took about: %s" % (time.ctime(), onloadPerformance))

        driver.refresh()
    except TimeoutException:
        print("It took too long")

        driver.quit()
```

I have two questions:

1. Is it a good idea to keep refresh the page and print the page loading time? Does it have any risk?
2. Anything needs to get improvement for my code?

Someone suggested using docker and jerkin when I searched any suggestions on Google, but it will need to download more things. This code will be package into exe in the end and let others to use. It will be good if it does not acquire many software packages.

Thank you very much as I am a fresh man in the web side. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: You're using `driver` definition outside the loop, but `driver.quit()` inside a loop. Try to either define `driver` inside a loop or (better) move `driver.quit()` outside the loop

Comment: @Andersson Thanks for helping to look into this issue. I have edited my question and pasted my latest code.

Comment: Try to replace `driver.quit()` in `except` block with `break` and add `driver.quit()` outside of `while` loop

Comment: @Andersson Thank you very much for your help.